# Pass argument like bind event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how I can do this...

```
function action(param)
{
   $(body).param('Blah');
}

action('append');
```

If you understood me, is there any way of that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript. You should just pass in the function, and use `apply` to invoke it on `$('body')`, rather than passing in a string which may or may not actually point to a function:

```
function action(fn) {
  fn.call($('body'), 'Blah');
}

action($.fn.append);
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that "instance" methods applying to specific sets of elements aren't available via the global jQuery object. Thanks.